# Can I create a table (if not exists) from Rose::DB::Object metadata?

Tags: perl, orm, rose-db-object

I'm having trouble finding it in the [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/) -- is there a way to create a table (`IF NOT EXISTS`) from manually-entered `Rose::DB::Object` metadata?

I'm using SQLite as an engine, if it happens to matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is possible to create a [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/) class (as a `.pm` file on disk or just in memory) from an existing SQL schema using [Rose::DB::Object::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Loader.pm), there is currently no built-in way to do the reverse: generate an SQL table definition from a [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/) class definition.

To do such a thing, I suggest looking into using [SQL::Translator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Translator/).  All of the [Rose::DB::Object metadata](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Metadata.pm) is readily available.  It'd just be a matter of adapting it to suit `SQL::Translator`'s requirements.  If you'd like more guidance or some help doing this, I suggest asking around on the [RDBO mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rose-db-object).

Comment: Certainly a well-qualified answer. ;-)